# Why do we install software via `.dmg` files?

Tags: install, software, dmg

When I want to install software, I typically download a `.dmg` (Disk iMaGe) file. When I open it, this `.dmg` file looks like what I would call a "virtual disk" (hence its name I presume) and is listed in  `Finder` under `devices`. It is also listed in `Disk Utility` under `Disk Images` and it seems like it can be erased or unmounted just like any other disk.

- What is the logic for which software needs to be installed with such a "virtual disk"?
- Why doesn't it come as a simple binary file or I don't know what?

Comment: Installing software can always cause **d**a**m**a**g**e.

Comment: A simple binary file would be an installer.  With DMG you just copy the application without running an installer.

Comment: Most Mac apps look like single files, but in reality are "application bundles", basically folder with many files inside. Finder displays it as single entity, but you can right click on them and select "Open contents" to inspect files inside. So, "simple binary" won't work.

Comment: **History:** https://blog.barthe.ph/2011/04/05/dmg_history/

Comment: The last paragraph should be a separate question as it is giving rise to separate answers

Answer (score 37, accepted):

DMGs have a few key features which make them superior to plain old zips

- They’re a full file system (meaning they can store file permissions, have custom folder backgrounds, etc)
- They support “mandatory” EULAs before mounting which is nice for legal stuff
- Provide a more reliable execution environment. If you have to do absolute path stuff for installation (which tbh you shouldn’t) you can prepare the DMG, mark it as read-only and use that to install

Really the key feature is that they support the full HFS+ filesystem. Zip (commonly, Linux versions sometimes support permissions) is stupid and only supports bundling files and folders and nothing else. No metadata, just the files.

Comment: Additional points: starting in 10.12, .dmg files can be code-signed for integrity (.zip files can *contain* signed code, but cannot themselves be signed in a way that'll survive downloading). Also, the "simple binary" option doesn't work at all, because most macOS software comes as packages -- folders with complex (hidden) internal structure -- rather than plain files.

Comment: @Sirens He's talking about signing the disk image itself, not the contents of the disk image. See [TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG18).

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Huh, I retract that! I didn't realize the term "code sign" is used with archives

Comment: "Zip is stupid and only supports..." - I disagree with that assessment. Just because something is simple doesn't mean it's stupid. Simplicity is a virtue, and rarely is (often invisible) file metadata of any value in a distributed installer.

Comment: @Dai he means stupid as in dumb; the program doesn’t know what it’s doing - not that it’s useless.

Comment: I suppose ZIP is not too much of a good comparison. Why not e.g. compressed TAR like `tar.gz`? It does store permissions.

Comment: @Dai, "rarely is (often invisible) file metadata of any value in a distributed installer" -- true on many other platforms, but Apple has a long history of storing critical content (ie. icons!) in "resource forks" (these days, xattrs).

Comment: @Ruslan: But so does ZIP?

Comment: Zip does preserve permissions (when compressed/decompressed by `zip`, Finder, or `ditto`), and resource forks (Finder or `ditto` only).

Comment: @Sirens, Are file permissions even portable? What's a use case for that?

Comment: @Sirens, Is there **really any point** in custom background images? Who came up with that idea anyway?

Comment: @Pacerier Background images (and custom folder images) are meant for install disk customizations to provide essentially digital box art

Comment: @Sirens, Do you not agree that it's a relic of the 1990s and modern OSes should do away with this concept?

Comment: @Pacerier No, and that’s hardly the point of this question anyways

Answer (score 3):

Mac software can be delivered as as a `.app` application bundle (essentially a folder containing all the program resources) or as a `.pkg` installer which is a program that installs applications in a similar way to Windows.

Only command line tools are available as plain binaries which would then be copied to somewhere in the user's `PATH` such as `/usr/local/bin`.

These can be packaged in an OS X/macOS disk image (`.dmg`) or a traditional archive format such as `.zip` or `.tar`.

---

> What is the logic for which software needs to be installed with such a "virtual disk"?

This is largely up to the developer. A `.dmg` is just a virtual hard drive not an installer. The choice to utilise a `.dmg` is about packaging rather than installation.

If an application is a simple `.app` bundle it is self contained and can be run by double clicking it. It is commonly copied to `/Applications` for convenience.

In addition to encryption and EULAs on opening, the benefit of a `.dmg` over an archive type is branding. `.dmg`s can be given custom icons, custom background images and the layout of the contents can be fixed. `.dmg`s are commonly also read only so the contents will remain exactly as the developer intended it.

They also force the user to select where they would like an application; when you unzip an archive the contents will typically be extracted to wherever the archive was located. In contrast, `.dmg`s will mount in the filesystem and then the `.app` bundle must be explicitly copied.

---

> Why doesn't it come as a simple binary file or I don't know what?

A Mac application is more than just a binary. In addition to the the binary (located at `<appname>.app/Contents/MacOS/`) an `.app` includes a number of resources in `<appname>.app/Contents/Resources/`. These resources include icons, graphics and localisation files such as `en.lproj`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other usage for .dmg files other than Software
>   installation?

Another useful feature about DMGs (since you asked about other uses) is the ability to create an encrypted storage space and store files in that protected space. Useful if you want to protect some files, but not encrypt your entire main hard disk.

See [Disk Utility for macOS Sierra: Create a disk image using Disk Utility](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22247) for more info on creating encrypted .dmg files.

Comment: Encryption however is already doable without the need for `.dmg`. Doesn't  Unix encrypt?

Comment: @ Pacerier -- oh for sure -- like everything with Linux/Unix, there's more than one way to do something.